# Applying chaining pattern to creation of an element and its children?

Tags: javascript, chaining

I have a function

```
function createElement(name, value, parent) {
    var ele = document.createElement(name);
    ele.innerHTML = value;
    parent.appendChild(ele);

    return ele;
}
```

which creates the element, adds a value and appends it to its parent. Now I wanted to make it chainable, where you call a function multiple times on the same object.

Using the above function, to produce `<div><span></span></div>`, it would look like

```
var div1 = createElement('div', 'Div1', document.body);
var span = createElement('span', 'Span', div1);
```

So to get the expected output through Chaining, for instance, I would like to apply

```
document.body.createChild('div', 'Div').createChild('a', 'Anchor')
```

… and so on, where the `createChild` function takes in two parameters the name of the element and the text value.

Comment: I’d say don’t bother. Is there really such a huge difference between `var span = createElement('span','Span',div1);` and `var span = div1.createElement('span', 'Span');`?

Comment: @Barmar not really, that's how i coded it?

Comment: I didn't say anything! All I did was fix the markup in your question.

Comment: And how would you want it to look like with "chaining"? I don't really get what you want (and why you want it). Chaining is not suited well for a) constructors/factories and b) nested structures - which you have both

Comment: Can you post what you want your js api call to look like and what the expected dom results would be?

Comment: @Scott i made some edits in the actual question let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: That pattern would need you [extend the native DOM interfaces](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), which is despised.

Comment: jquery already does something similar with `append`. The problem is chaining, the way you describe, doesn't contextually make sense unless you are _always_ nesting.  But what if you want a `ul` and 2 `li`s  `ul.createChild('li','1').createChild('li','2')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in how to create a chaining pattern in JS. Here is an example:

```
var chain = function (el) {
    return {
        createElement: function (name, value) {
            var ele = document.createElement(name);
            ele.innerHTML = value;
            el.appendChild(ele);
            return chain(ele);
        }
    };
};

var el = document.getElementById('test');
chain(el).createElement('div','Div1').createElement('span','Span');
```

which would result in

```
<div id="test"><div>Div1<span>Span</span></div></div>
```

But you would need something *fancier* if you wanted to chain lists to an element.  Or for this example

```
var ul = chain(ul);
ul.createElement('li', '1');
ul.createElement('li', '2');
```

Comment: Please make `createElement` a prototype method. And invoke `chain` with `new`, or don't write it as a constructor.